# How must be real transistor model?

Tags: transistors, diodes, capacitance, model

Transistors have some capacitance value. So where do i must put that capacitance when i want to draw real model of transistor. Also second question same about diodes? Can anyone draw simple real model transistor and diode?

Comment: The book I have about semiconductors have 150 pages just dedicated to a diode and its model. It appears that you want someone to draw a "simple" model that's still "real". It doesn't work like that.

Comment: the transistor has capacitance between all the legs, there's a capacitor from base to emitter, from emitter to collector and from collector to base. With the diode, well there's only two legs so there's only one place you can put that capacitor. Problem is, if you want a *really real* model, it's going to need a bit more than just some capacitance, there's a whole slew of all kinds of semiconductor voodoo going on in the average transistor, although, I suspect that you don't need a super accurate really real model so just stick with the capacitors between all the terminals, 10-100pF or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many models for transistors and diodes.

The point about a model is that you don't attempt to capture all the behaviour of the device, **only** the parts of the behaviour that are important to you at the time. For instance, a map is a model of a neighbourhood, which is adequate if you want to find your way from A to B, but not if you want to see what sort of dirt is underfoot at C.

For a really simple model of a silicon diode, which is probably good enough for using for 95% of times anybody thinks about how to design in a diode, a 0.7v battery in series with an ideal diode, which is a perfect 'conducts forward, doesn't conduct backwards' element.

For a really simple '90% of times adequate' model of a transistor (for biassing, for low frequencies), it's a diode connected base to emitter, with a current source collector to emitter, pulling down hFE times the base current.

But those two models are way short of reality, and do not address anything much above DC or very slow AC.

If you add only one capacitor to the transistor model, add the 'Miller' collector to base capacitance. That is the nasty one, the one that looks small on a data sheet, and kills the gain at high frequency when you build a common emitter amplifier, because its effect at the base is multiplied by the gain of the stage. Ouch!

To improve the diode model, change the battery and perfect diode to the classic exponential conduction function, add some series resistance (for high current behaviour), a parasitic capacitor between the terminals, and some charge storage in the junction (for switch off behaviour, only for junction diodes, not schottkies, which need a reverse leakage term (temperature dependent) instead).

To improve the transistor further, you could fix up the base emitter diode, add stray C to all pairs of terminals, and series resistance to the collector. But it's doubtful whether you would ever need a model that was better than BE_diode+CE_current_source+CB_Miller_Cap, without having to go for the more comprehensive Gummel-Poon model, which as it turns out is not adequate to completely model what a transistor does in all circumstances.